# Call IQueryable as an IEnumerable, filter done on client side?

Tags: c#, iqueryable

I was reading an article here: [N-tier Zombie with wcf](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474212/Zombie-Explorer-A-N-Tier-application-from-top-to-b).

I came across the following statement "zombieRepository.GetAll().Where(funcComp)", `GetAll()` return an `IQueryable`, but the `where` statement is passed in a `Func<>` parameter, which actually call the `IQueryable` interface as an `IEnumerable` interface.

The problem with this call is that the filter is done at client side (read all `dtos.ZombieIncident` out, then apply filter), not at sql server side, is my understanding correct?

code snippet:

```
var paramStart = Expression.Parameter(typeof(dtos.ZombieIncident), "x");
                Expression<Func<dtos.ZombieIncident, bool>> func = Expression.Lambda<Func<dtos.ZombieIncident, bool>>(
                            Expression.Call(Expression.Property(paramStart,
                                typeof(dtos.ZombieIncident).GetProperty(propertyName).GetGetMethod()),
                                typeof(String).GetMethod(searchType.ToString(), new Type[] { typeof(String) }),
                                new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(searchValue, typeof(string)) }),
                    new ParameterExpression[] { paramStart });

                Func<dtos.ZombieIncident, bool> funcComp = func.Compile();

                foreach (dtos.ZombieIncident zombie in zombieRepository.GetAll().Where(funcComp).ToList())
                {
                    zombies.Add(ZombieIncidentDTOMapper.FromDTO(zombie));
                }
```

Comment: Check your title ICurable :) or IQueryable? not sure if zombies have some special interfaces....

Comment: Do you have sql profiler? If so, run it and it will tell you what the actual query is doing. In looking quickly at the code, it looks like it's querying on the DB side.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different `Where` extension methods:

[`System.Linq.Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.where%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

- Accepts a `Func<TSource, Boolean>` parameter
- Filters the collection in memory

[`System.Linq.Queryable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.queryable.where%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

- Accepts an `Expression<Func<TSource, Boolean>>` parameter
- Filters the collection at the data source

If you are not sure which method you are using, put your cursor over it and hit F1. You will be sent to a page corresponding to one of the links above.